# How do I save the state of a selected item from recycle view?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have multiple items in my chatListLinearLayout, I would like to update my messageStatus  to say something such as "Item selected" for the selected item. I managed to do this successfully but I would like to save this so the next time the user reopens the app it will remain.Could someone assist me?

```
displayMessagesRecycleView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {
                        CircleImageView profileImage = view.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
                        LinearLayout chatListLinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.chatListLinearLayout);
                        final TextView messageStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.user_status);


                        chatListLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                messageStatus.setText("Item selected");



                            }
                        });
```

Comment: You can use Boolean object in Model class and use `view model` to save live data.

Comment: I don't understand could you be more descriptive?

Answer (score 1):

You can `setSelected(true);` for view and set one boolean in you object model
and for save selected item state you need to save your list into sharedPrefs or sqlite database

Comment: Could you be more descriptive?